# Where is my software installation?

Tags: filesystem

I'm kind of new to Linux. I installed a program (Sublime Text) and now I need to see the folder it is in. I can't find it under `usr/bin`, so, is there any other place wher I should look? Or ... how can I find out where to locate the folder?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @Seth Good question. I installed it a year ago. I don't remember how... maybe with `apt-get`.

Comment: You can find out, whether a package is installed through the package manager, even if you don't know its exact name. For Sublime Text, you could run `dpkg -l sublime\*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know the name of this program's executable. After you know it, just run 'which executable_name' and it will show you the path to the executable file.

Comment: ok, this worked thanks. Excecutable for sublime text is "subl" if anyone finds this useful.

Comment: If installed through apt-get or dpkg, you could also ask dpkg to list any file belonging to a specific package, e.g. `dpkg -L sublime-text`.